# Is there some tool to convert anki cards (.apk) to org drill files (.org with special markers)?

Tags: org-mode, org-drill

**Short Background**

I started learning Emacs 5 months ago and it has been a tough but **awesome** experience! I would like to get more muscle memory on some keybindings and commands and I think a flashcard system could help me. Thus, I tried using Anki. I even found this [Anki deck](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/2000749682) that seems thorough.

Unfortunately, Anki is too expensive for me. As a consequence, I was looking for (cheaper) alternatives. As an accident, I came across **org drill**. What a good surprise! Using Emacs itself as a flesh card *tool* to improve my learning of Emacs :)

**Real question**

1 - Is there a way to convert this [anki card file](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/2000749682) (`.akp`) to `.org` (with org-drill markers)?

2 - In case there is not, what would be your suggestion to tackle the problem? Would you build a short script to do the conversion? How would be the draft of this script? Maybe a task that is too challenging? Is it hard to know the potential quality of the file conversion without really trying?

3 -  After knowing that I want to train Emacs keybindings with `ord-drill`, what would be your suggestion? Do you know a `.org` file to train on org-drill about Emacs?

Thanks

Comment: I'll give you my own very personal opinion: you're "over-engineering" your Emacs journey. I've used org-drill and it certainly helped me but I don't see how it could in this case. Learning Emacs is rather easy. I have been using Emacs for 3 years and learn things EVERY day. Use emacs, discover and explore it (hit `C-h C-h`), read parts of the manuals (Emacs, packages, Elisp, etc) as the need comes, etc. The only external source worth reading is "Mastering Emacs". Emacs is just a tool. There's usually REAL work to be done.

Comment: You may find these ref cards useful: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/.

Comment: You *could* manipulate the `.akp` file: it's a zip archive that contains a Sqlite3 database. The database contains five tables, presumably to satisfy the needs of the anki applciation, but the `notes` table contains the text of the cards. But I agree with @aadcg: instead of writing programs to scrape the database and make cards in a different format, you could do the Emacs tutorial `C-h t`) and read the manual (`C-h i g(emacs)`) and practice, practice, practice. It's no different than playing the piano, except that it doesn't sound so bad when you hit the wrong keys :-)

Comment: Thanks, guys. I decided to try this out: https://github.com/pdelfino/emacs-flashcards Let's see how it goes!